# iOS UIView Background Becomes Transparent When Moved

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Right now, I'm using autolayout to update the constraints of this view so that it gets shifted upwards when the keyboard shows. Here is the method:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)sender
{
    if ( [self.yelpSearchTextField isFirstResponder] || [self.timeTextField isFirstResponder] || [self.radiusTextField isFirstResponder] ) {
        CGRect frame = [sender.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
        CGRect viewFrame = self.yelpSearchView.frame;
        self.keyboardHeightConstraint.constant = frame.size.height + viewFrame.size.height;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

It works fine, but for some reason, whenever the keyboard appears, the background of the view becomes transparent.

Before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE0AM.jpg

After: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzMQC.jpg

Any ideas why this is happening?

Here is a picture of my constraints:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOSt2.jpg

Even weirder behavior! Take a look at this - if I move the starting position of the view like in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UEQd.jpg

Then when it moves up, only half the view seems to show up. What could this mean?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXDFf.jpg

Comment: try moving the self.view as well as u update the constraints of the keyboard.

Comment: just write this `self.view.frame = CGRectMake (0,-200,320,568);` You can set frame as par requirement. and set it back when hiding keyboard like `self.view.frame = CGRectMake (0, 0,320,568);`

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your constraints?

Comment: http://imgur.com/YlfzwhA

Comment: I don't understand how that helps - shouldn't the constraint be enough to push the view upwards?

Comment: Your last picture shows 2 Searchbars and 2 Views in the hierarchy of your controller's view. It would be interesting if you expanded all those views in a new screenshot so people can see your entire hierarchy. Your problem sounds like the View holding all the labels (which has the constraint whose constant your updating) has a transparent backgroundColor, and the other View (whose constraints don't get updated) holds the white background.

Comment: I've checked that already. As you can see, the view holding all the labels as a background color of White and an alpha of 1. This is correct, yea? http://i.imgur.com/RYkUAw2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.keyboardHeightConstraint.constant = frame.size.height + viewFrame.size.height;
```

This was my problem! I have no idea why I was setting the bottom constraint to this - I only needed to set it to the frame.size.height. I was adding too much extra, so the view was getting pushed past the visible area. I changed it to

```
self.keyboardHeightConstraint.constant = frame.size.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

First reason: Your problem is in your notification method

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)sender;
```

Sender is a uitextfield or uitextview and you set frame of yelpSearchView. I think the  yelpSearchView background color is Clearcolor.

Second reason: In your design may have a problem. 
I see your constraints picture.
just Put the search bar in a view and set frame of that view

Comment: Where do I set the frame of yelpSearchView? I believe I'm just changing the value of the constraint constant to "push" the view upwards.

Comment: Yes? The background of the searchView is a white color.

Comment: No i want to say you put your Searchbar in an another view other than mapview superview

Answer (score 0):

Try to add height constraint for your view. I suppose, it don't clip subviews and height = 0.